# ML5.JS objectDetector.detect is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, machine-learning, p5.js

I'm quite new to ml5 and p5 libraries and during implementation to my Angular project I'm receiving this error:

```
TypeError: this.objectDetector.detect is not a function
```

After logging objectDetector object console shows this:

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
```

p5 drawing working good but combined with ml5 is not working.

Here's my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';

declare let ml5: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-found',
  templateUrl: './new-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-found.component.scss']
})
export class NewFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  objectDetector;
  img;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const sketch = (s) => {

      s.preload = () => {
        this.objectDetector = ml5.objectDetector('cocossd');
        console.log('detector object is loaded', this.objectDetector);
        this.img = s.loadImage('https://i.imgur.com/Mzh4cHR.jpg');
      }

      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(700, 700).parent('test-canvas');
        this.objectDetector.detect(this.img, this.gotResult);
        s.image(this.img, 0, 0);
      };

      s.draw = () => {

      };
    }

    let canvas = new p5(sketch);  
  }

  gotResult(error, results) {

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(results);

        //drawResults(results);

    }
}

}
```

ml5 library is imported in `<HEAD>` of my `index.html` file.

Does someone know how to get rid of this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. The `ml5.objectDetector('cocossd');` function must be marked as await because it takes quite long time to execute. Below is working code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';

declare let ml5: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-found',
  templateUrl: './new-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-found.component.scss']
})
export class NewFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  objectDetector;
  img;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.objectDetector = await ml5.objectDetector('cocossd');

    const sketch = (s) => {

      s.preload = () => {
        console.log(ml5);   
        console.log('detector object is loaded', this.objectDetector);
        this.img = s.loadImage('https://i.imgur.com/Mzh4cHR.jpg');
      }

      s.setup = () => {
        s.createCanvas(700, 700).parent('test-canvas');
        this.objectDetector.detect(this.img, this.gotResult);
        s.image(this.img, 0, 0);
      };

      s.draw = () => {

      };
    }

    let canvas = new p5(sketch);  
  }

  gotResult(error, results) {

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        console.log(results);

        //drawResults(results);

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Thats why I love C# conventions of adding `Async` at the end of each async method so you know to await it....

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the library has not fully loaded yet. I would create a polling technique here where you keep checking if the value has been initialized and only then proceed.

This is the code I use for polling that `xola` script has loaded:

```
let subscription = interval(1000)
        .pipe(timeout(3 * 60 * 1000))
        .subscribe({
            next: () => {
                if (this.window.xola) {
                    const xola = this.window.xola();
                    subscription.unsubscribe();
                    this.xolaSubject.next(xola);
                }
            },
            error: (error) => {
                if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                    console.error('Xola took too long to load, check your connection.');
                }
                subscription.unsubscribe();
            },
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I set onload callback on script tag to check when library is loaded and after load confirmation error still occurs.

Comment: put a breakpoint right before `ml5.objectDetector('cocossd');` and see if `window['ml5]` is found as a function. Perhaps that import doesn't work as expected

Comment: It is found. Function .objectDetector also appears. To be fair - I'm out of ideas;)